# Tamaño de un tercer array creado por otros 2

Tags: java, array

supongamos que lleno dos arrays por teclado de diferentes tamaños y quiero sumarlos (posicion 1 + posicion 1 y los mismo con las demas) entonces necesito un tercer vector del cual no tengo muy claro que dimension tiene que tener, siempre que intento me sale este error **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2**

Comment: las posiciones en un array parten del indice 0, los 3 arrays deben tener la misma longitud ,seria bueno que adjuntaras tu código ;)

Comment: "lleno dos arrays por teclado de diferentes tamaños", tu tercer array, tiene el tamaño del mas grande, porque estas sumando cada posicion no? y de paso, si uno se acaba antes, lo dejas de sumar.. no?